# How can I create a custom shortcode that will return a custom post type by ID?

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, shortcode

Please excuse my ignorance, this seems simple but I can't figure it out and I've been rushing to hack things together. I can't find anything online to help me out.

**What I have:**
A custom post type named "case_study". There are going to be a lot of these published and they will be used in various places throughout the site, some of them more than once.

**What I need:**
To print an individual case study where needed, by ID. I feel like using a shortcode would be the most obvious way to do this, but I'm failing to get there. (Perhaps there is a better user-friendly option?)

I would like my shortcode to work like this: [case_study id=31]

Here is my plugin code. This currently prints the entire case study category when I use the short code:

```
//Case study Post Type
add_action('init', 'register_cpt_case_study');

function register_cpt_case_study() {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Case Studies', 'case_study'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Case Study', 'case_study'),
        'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'case_study'),
        'add_new_item' => _x('Add New Case Study', 'case_study'),
        'edit_item' => _x('Edit Case Study', 'case_study'),
        'new_item' => _x('New Case Study', 'case_study'),
        'view_item' => _x('View Case Study', 'case_study'),
        'search_items' => _x('Search Case Studies', 'case_study'),
        'not_found' => _x('No case studies found', 'case_study'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => _x('No case studies found in Trash', 'case_study'),
        'parent_item_colon' => _x('Parent Case Study:', 'case_study'),
        'menu_name' => _x('Case Studies', 'case_study'),
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'description' => 'A case study plugin for better management and organization',
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor'),
        'public' => false,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'http:www.changethis.com', //change this icon
        'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'has_archive' => false,
        'query_var' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post'
    );

    register_post_type('case_study', $args);
}

// THE SHORTCODE FOR CASE STUDIES
function case_study_shortcode($atts) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'id' => '',
                    ), $atts));
//The Query
    query_posts('post_type=case_study');
//The Loop
    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
            echo '<h3>';
            echo the_title();
            echo '</a></h3>';
            echo the_content();
        endwhile;
    else:
    endif;

//Reset Query
    wp_reset_query();
}

add_shortcode('case_study', 'case_study_shortcode');
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please take a look at [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts) for why to not use `query_posts()`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found a simple answer to my problem. This is the shortcode function I ended up using to get my desired result:

```
function cpt_case_study_func($atts){

extract( shortcode_atts( array(

    'id' => null,

), $atts ) );

    $post = get_post($id);
    $content = '<div class="case-study"><h3>' . $post->post_title . '</h3>   <p>' . $post->post_content . '</p></div>';
    return $content;
    }

    add_shortcode('case_study','cpt_case_study_func');
```

Thanks to help from Kyle on [this post](http://wpquestions.com/question/showChrono/id/8901)